# Does MetaBase provide drill-down functionality?

Tags: visualization, drilldown, metabase

I want to implement drilling in metabase dashboards.
I discovered 'Custom Destinations' option which navigates user to any link upon clicking on a chart, but it does not carry forward the filter for selected dimension.

Is there any way we can implement drill-down functionality in MetaBase?

I linked a chart to another dashboard but it didn't filter by the selected dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Metabase's [drill-through docs](https://www.metabase.com/learn/questions/drill-through) you can pass a filter onto the destination question or dashboard **if the destination has filtered columns set up**.

On the card in the dashboard that should be doing the navigation, click on:

`Click behaviour` -> `Go to custom destination` -> select destination question/dashboard under `Link To` -> the possible destination filters will appear under `Pass values to this dashboard's filters (optional)`.